# Tableau: keeping results independent of view / filter

Tags: tableau, aggregation

I am using Tableau Desktop 2021.1.4

Suppose that my source sales data consists of 4 columns Region (dimension with values: N,E,W,S), Type (dimension with values: Furniture, Electronics, Appliances), Year (dimension with values: 2021, 2020, 2020), and sales ($).

I would like to generate a Calculated Field, say "Sum of Sales", where the summation:

1. is always over **all** the regions and **all** the types, regardless of what is in the view
2. can also be over the different years or can be filtered by year

I thought:

```
{Exclude [Region], [Type]:
    sum([Sales])
}
```

would do the trick, but, for example, when the view is: [Region][Type] in the Rows and [Year] in the Columns, and I filter the region, Sum of Sales becomes smaller accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [FIXED Level of Detail Expressions](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_fixed.htm), and see this information on [Filters and Level of Detail Expressions](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_filters.htm).

FIXED could also be combined with adding filters to context:

> FIXED calculations are applied before dimension filters, so unless you
> promote the fields on your Filter shelf to Improve View Performance
> with Context Filters, they will be ignored.